# Does not return the index of the student, always returns -1 (Array)

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am learning java for the first time because of my interest in programming and there is a problem with this program I am working on.

This code is meant to return the index of an agent in question or -1 if not found but it keeps returning -1.

```
private Agent [] agents; //an array of Agent

public int findAgentLocation (String name)
 {
      for (int index = 0; index < agents.length; index++)
    {
      if (agents[index]).equals(name)){
        return index;
      }
    }
    return -1;
   }
  }
```

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Does your code compile? This line `if (agents[index]).equals(name))` looks weird for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this: `if (agents[index].equals(name)){` , you are essentially comparing two different datatypes ('Agent' and 'String'). Java will do an object comparison and hence they will never be equal. So you end up getting back "-1" always.

Assuming Agent class has a name variable, You'll need to do something like this:

`if (agents[index].getName().equals(name)){`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your equals(String) in Agent